# How to store and retrieve date in MySQL based on users local time

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime

I am pulling user data from a MySQL database. The table I am retrieving data from had a datetime column called 'created_at', that is storing dates as UTC, which is the servers timezone.

How can I retrieve the users data, including the 'created_at column' and display it in the users current timezone.

I am trying the following, but it is not working for me:

```
const mysqlDate = '2022-05-20T16:46:05.000Z'
    var date = mysqlDate.replace("Z", "+00:00").replace("T", " ");
    var d = new Date(date);
    var timezone = 
    Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone; //Australia/Brisbane
    var result = d.toLocaleString("en-US", {
      timeZone: usersTimezone,
```

Comment: Usually one would always store dates in a standard time zone (UTC, generally) and then convert as needed in the application.  Storing different time zones for different rows of the same column would lead to lots of confusion.

Comment: Thanks @David, to my understanding when recording in a datetime field the time zone is remove, is that correct? If not, how could I convert it to the users current timezone on the front end? Would I just create a new Date object and the use toLocal()